# Adding item to listfragment

Tags: android

i have fragment and when i press a button it goes to an activity with an edittext and the text i enter need to go in my listfragment but it just crash here is my code i know the problem  corresponds to `lst.add(message)` by referring to the logcat but can't find why it doesn't work it seems to be a NPE.

log :

```
18187-18187/com.example.gweltaz.coffy3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131074, result=2, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.gweltaz.coffy3/com.example.gweltaz.coffy3.Nav}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3000)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3043)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1188)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.gweltaz.coffy3.F1_fr.onActivityResult(F1_fr.java:68)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:163)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2996)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3043)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1188)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Main fragment (updated ) :

```
    public class F1_fr extends ListFragment {
       View rootview;
       TextView textView1;
       ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
       ArrayList<String> lst;
       String[] month = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.f1_lay,container,false);

        textView1=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(month));
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);

        setListAdapter(aa);
        rootview.findViewById(R.id.semi_transparent).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ajout.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }
        });
        return rootview; 
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == 2){
            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            if (lst == null ) {lst = new ArrayList<String>(); lst.add(message); }
        }
    }  
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Child Fragment :

```
public class ajout extends ActionBarActivity { 
    EditText editText2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ajout);
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    }

    public void btn(View view) {
        String message=editText2.getText().toString();
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);
        setResult(2,intent);
        finish();//finishing activity
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ajout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you get in `message` in *onActivityResult*?

Comment: You need to override onActivityResult  in FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

You have used *`startActivityForResult`* so you can access data in *`onActivityResult`* method which you need to *override* in FragmentActivity only.

So just use *OVERRIDE* before the method.

And make sure you keep check for all null values before doing any operation on *lst* and *aa* :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if(requestCode == 2)
        {
             if(lst==null)
             {
                 lst = new ArrayList<String>();
                 lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(month));
             }
             lst.add(message);
             // update value in list

             if(aa==null)
                   aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst);
             aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: I added an override and it still crashing

Comment: where have you overridden this method ?

Comment: and the logcat says that there is always an error at the line 68 which corresponds to lst.add

Comment: then lst is NULL. check for it `if(lst!=null) lst.add()`. CHeck message too

Comment: If i am not wrong, the list is in Fragment and the metghod is in FragmentActivity.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not because override because i did the thing before with a textview instead of a list and its worked perfectly

Comment: Did you check what is NULL at that line . is it lst or message ?

Comment: Id i check if(lst!=null) lst.add() it no longer crash after pressing button but it didnt had me anything to my list

Comment: Ya so its clear lst is null.  So if lst is null, initialize it and then add it :)

Comment: how to initialize it because i did this final ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();    (sorry i am a begginer

Comment: Ya do the same. if `(lst == null ) {lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add(message); }`

Comment: yeah that's what i did but the content of the list didnt change

Comment: where is *notifyDataSetChanged*? check my code in answer

Comment: i did this before and it crashed

Comment: But before that you haven't checked `lst==null`

Comment: you forgot this ? String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

Comment: Do i need to provide you full code or a *snippet* that should resolve your error ? its obvious that you need that line

Comment: because everything is working until i add : aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Then *aa is NULL*. you must use `notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh the list content.